# is it neccessary to have a controller for every model while using mvc

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC. Someone please tell me that is it necessary to have a controller for every model, or we can use a single controller for more than one models. Your answers will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can load as many models as your app needs in one/same controller. Or even you can autoload them in `APPPATH . 'config/autoload.php'` and use them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load any number of model in one controller or a model can be loaded in multiple controller. codeigniter is not following any convention and hence you can use it as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have a controller for each model, the controller interacts with views and data, so each controller can have more than one model depending of what you want to do and how you want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "YES", we can use a single controller for more than one models. Besides, I want to make you clear that a controller doesnt't have any model. A controller use(not have) one or more models. They(controller and models) are not bind with one another. A model can be used in different controllers at the same time a controller can use as much model as it needs to use.